# mlr3 - confidence interval for predictions

Tags: r, mlr3

After tuning a learner and using it, we can use it to make predictions through the command line

```
predict(Learner, newdata, predict_type="response")
```

But, how do we compute confidence intervals for predictions?

---

```
task <- TaskRegr$new("data", data, "y")
learner <- lrn("regr.xgboost")
preprocess <- po("scale", param_vals = list(center = TRUE, scale = TRUE))
pp <- preprocess %>>% learner
gg<- GraphLearner$new(pp)
gg$train(task)
predict(gg, newdata = pred, predict_type="reponse")
```

Comment: `predict_type = "se"`

Comment: It throws an error --- `Error: Predict type 'se' not available`. I'm using `regr.xgboost` in a `GraphLearner`.

Comment: Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce this please? You probably just have to adjust how the model is trained.

Comment: When I use `lrn("regr.featureless", predict_type = "se")` it shows not errors at all. `lrn("regr.xgboost", predict_type = "se")` throws `Error: Learner 'regr.xgboost' does not support predict type 'se'`, however. Is it just me?

Comment: No, not all learners support prediction errors, xgboost being one of them. You'll have to use a different learner to get error estimates.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Could you post this as a full answer? Thanks.

Comment: Done @pat-s. This comment is not at least 15 characters in length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all learners support prediction errors, xgboost being one of them. You'll have to use a different learner to get error estimates.