# mlr3 confidence interval for AUC and cvAUC

Tags: r, mlr3

I would like to calculate the confidence interval for area under the curve (AUC) and cross-validated (cv) AUC using `mlr3`

I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250284/mlr3-confidence-interval-for-predictions) that for a regression task this could be done with `predict_type = "se"`

I wonder how this could be done for AUC/cvAUC within `mlr3`

A solution outside of mlr3 for cvAUC is probosed in the update below).

Example data:

```r
# library
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlbench)

# get example data
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes, package="mlbench")
data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes

# make task
all.task <- TaskClassif$new("all.data", data, target = "diabetes")

#make a learner 
learner <- lrn("classif.log_reg", predict_type = "prob")

# resample 
rr = resample(all.task, learner, rsmp("cv"))
#> INFO  [12:19:45.662] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 5/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.741] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 8/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.780] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 10/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.805] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 2/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.831] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 6/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.859] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 1/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.899] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 9/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.926] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 7/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.954] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 3/10) 
#> INFO  [12:19:45.995] [mlr3]  Applying learner 'classif.log_reg' on task 'all.data' (iter 4/10)

# get AUC
rr$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))
#> classif.auc 
#>   0.8297186
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Update:

Outside of `mlr3` I would do it with the `cvAUC` package

```
library(cvAUC)
library(tidyverse)

# extract predictions
rr$predictions() -> cv_pred_model

# prepare data for cv ci
cv_pred_model %>%
  map(.,as.data.table) %>% 
  map_df(~as.data.frame(.x), .id="fold") -> go

# calculate ci cv
ci.cvAUC(predictions=go$prob.1,labels=go$truth,folds=go$fold,confidence=0.95)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no builtin way for mlr3 to calculate AUC uncertainty that is as comfortable calculating the measure by itself (i.e. nothing with `$aggregate()`). Instead you can call `cvAUC::ci.cvAUC` and give it the required data:

The `ResampleResult` object `rr` has the method `$predictions()`, which gives you the true value, as well as the predicted scores, for each resampling fold. You can use the `data.table::rbindlist()` function with `idcol` set to get a table of all ground truths, all predictions, and an indicator denoting the resampling fold (you have to turn the `Prediction` objects into `data.table` for this). These are all information you need for `ci.cvAUC`.

```r
print(rr$predictions())
#> [[1]]
#> <PredictionClassif> for 77 observations:
#>     row_ids truth response   prob.neg   prob.pos   
#>           2   neg      neg 0.94955791 0.05044209
#>           6   neg      neg 0.85101781 0.14898219
#>          13   neg      pos 0.22516526 0.77483474
#> ---
#>         744   pos      pos 0.33871290 0.66128710
#>         745   neg      pos 0.06836943 0.93163057
#>         755   pos      pos 0.27998597 0.72001403
#>
#> [[2]]
#> <PredictionClassif> for 77 observations:
#>     row_ids truth response  prob.neg  prob.pos
#>          18   pos      neg 0.8050657 0.1949343               
#> [....]

predictiontables <- lapply(rr$predictions(), data.table::as.data.table)
allpred <- data.table::rbindlist(predictiontables, idcol = "fold")
print(allpred)
#>      fold row_ids truth response  prob.neg   prob.pos
#>   1:    1       2   neg      neg 0.9495579 0.05044209
#>   2:    1       6   neg      neg 0.8510178 0.14898219
#>   3:    1      13   neg      pos 0.2251653 0.77483474
#>   4:    1      37   neg      pos 0.3366958 0.66330422
#>   5:    1      41   neg      pos 0.2578118 0.74218818
#>  ---
#> 764:   10     739   neg      neg 0.8232726 0.17672735
#> 765:   10     746   neg      neg 0.6842442 0.31575585
#> 766:   10     749   pos      pos 0.1735568 0.82644319
#> 767:   10     759   neg      neg 0.8184856 0.18151445
#> 768:   10     763   neg      neg 0.9075691 0.09243093

cvAUC::ci.cvAUC(predictions = allpred$prob.pos,
  labels = allpred$truth, folds = allpred$fold)
#> $cvAUC
#> [1] 0.8315585
#> 
#> $se
#> [1] 0.01511107
#> 
#> $ci
#> [1] 0.8019414 0.8611757
#> 
#> $confidence
#> [1] 0.95
#>
```

If you like terse `magrittr` code, the equivalent is

```r
library("data.table")
library("magrittr")

rr$predictions() %>%
  lapply(as.data.table) %>%
  rbindlist(idcol = "fold") %$%
  cvAUC::ci.cvAUC(predictions = prob.pos, labels = truth, folds = fold)
```

Note the AUC value I get differs from OP's because of random variance. `rr$aggregate()` agrees with cvAUC here:

```r
rr$aggregate(msr("classif.auc"))
#> classif.auc
#>   0.8315585
```